# Worm plot residuals graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics, regression, gamlss

I'm trying to plot the Worm plot residuals on a model fitted using the `gamlss` function from the `gamlss` package. The interest graph looks like the one below:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Initially, below is the computational routine referring to the use of the `wormplot_gg` function from the `childsds` package, however, the result expressed using the function described above is not looks like the example shown above, which is being applied to a dataset contained within R.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gamlss)
library(childsds)

head(Orange)
Dados <- Orange
Model <- gamlss(circumference~age, family=NO,data=Dados); Model
wp(Model)

wormplot_gg(m = Model)
```

Below are the traditional results via the `wp` function in the `gamlss` package.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

And finally, we have the results obtained through the `wormplot_gg` function from the `childsds` package. However, as already described, this one does not present itself in the way I am interested, that is, with the visual structure of the first figure.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Do you mean that you want the plot to look different? Like the theme and the colors?

Comment: I would like to get a graphic with a look and feel of the first image, ie with features from the ````ggplot2```` package.

Comment: the source code in childsds::wormplot_gg looks pretty simple (it could be much more complicated). You can remove the theme_minimal() and theme() lines to undo the custom theming and remove the customization in the geom_() lines

Comment: So, however, the function doesn't seem to accept some functionality from the ggplot2 package. I saw that you have a site containing the construction of the worm plot in ````ggplot2````, I even tried to reproduce it for my problem but I couldn't. Could you help me build this graph through ggplot2 considering the example in tuning through the ````gamlss```` package??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using qqplotr https://aloy.github.io/qqplotr/index.html with the `detrend=True` option

```
library(qqplotr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(z=rnorm(50))

ggplot(df, aes(sample=z)) +
  stat_qq_point(detrend = T) +
  stat_qq_band(detrend = T, color='black', fill=NA, size=0.5)
```

[image]

you can also add `geom_hline(yintercept = 0)`

**edit:**
In the case of using this with a gamlss model, the first have to extract the randomized residuals out of the model, which for gamlss  is done simply with the function `residuals`, so you can just do e.g., `df <- data.frame(z=residuals(Model))`  and then just continue with the rest of the code

Comment: Helo! I would like to know how it would be done through the adjustment considering a gamlss model... could you edit your answer considering the above case?

Comment: sorry, i don't know what you mean. what template?

Comment: I would like to perform the wormplot based on the results of the model adjusted via the gamlss function. Sorry! I expressed myself incorrectly.

Comment: Note that the wormplot performed above is based on the adjustment of a gamls model..